# Why I receive error LNK1561 "Entry point must be defined" when I compile a DLL Project?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-library

I try to compile a very simple dynamic library project as .dll file.
The name of the project is "Library".
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the project properties are these:

[Debug Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTcsy.png)

[Release Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Joy0A.png)

In the project there are two files only: ClassA.h and ClassA.cpp.

The code in ClassA.h is:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

using namespace std;

#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define CLASSA_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define CLASSA_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

class ClassA
{
public:
    static CLASSA_API void func();
};


#endif
```

The code in ClassA.cpp is:

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>


void ClassA::func()
{
    cout << "SUCCESS!" << endl;
}
```

When I try to compile this project I receive this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  LNK1561 entry point
>   must be defined   Library C:\Users\UX303\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\DLLTest\Library\LINK 1

Comment: did you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky737ya4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ?

Comment: Yes, but I have not had a good result.

Comment: This is quite hard to get wrong, the entrypoint is built into the C runtime library and not linking it produces a different error.  Only one thing I can think of, the Project > Properties > Linker > Advanced > "Entry Point" setting is used.  That can be a problem when you try to build the x64 flavor of the DLL, as shown in the screenshot, the name decoration applied to the function is different.  No leading underscore, no @ postfix.  Do beware that is quite risky to do this, the CRT won't be initialized.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is likely that your configuration is not right.

Be sure to double check your "Active Configuration" (Debug / Release), to see if you are really building a DLL.

I have just made such a mistake, and came across this question.

Comment: When you switch from debug to release the profile gets reset to an EXE, when it should be a DLL. So check the config.  

Also if you are deploying to another machine you must set it to Release.  And - I'm not sure if this is 100% required, but there is a package "Microsoft C++ Redistributable" that I installed on the client machine, once I did these two things the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

In 64 bit machine I was getting same error when 'Solution Platforms' set to 'x86'. The error goes away when I set the 'Solution Platforms' to 'x64'.

Comment: unbelievable, I spent an hour before i read this and realized my platform got set to x86 for some random reason